# Error from Angular, what AngularJS 1.3 wants for ngMessages injection

Tags: angularjs

I've included angular-messages.js as shown in my index below.  When I run my app, I get the error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngMessages', required 
       by directive 'ngMessage', can't be found!
```

My registration.js is very simple and I believe I did the dependency correctly.  it looks as follows:

```
angular.module('registrationController',
  ['ngMessages']).controller('RegistrationCtrl',
  ['$scope','ngMessages',
     function ($scope) {
         var vm = this;
     }]);

<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-resource.js"></script>

<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/registration.js"></script>
```

--

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" ng-submit="registerForm()"
      ng-controller="RegistrationCtrl">
```

I'm relatively new to angular so I'm not quite sure I get DI 100%.  I assumed that ngMessages is injected because of the array inclusion but since I'm not using it in the controller I don't need to mention it in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngMessages here is required in your module, but not your controller.

ngMessages is a directive not a service, look at this documentation

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages

this is how you define it as a requirement for your angularJs module

```
  angular.module('myModule', ['ngMessages']);
```

then you can use in your html like this :

```
<form name="myForm">
<input type="text" ng-model="field" name="myField" required minlength="5" />
<div ng-messages="myForm.myField.$error">
  <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
  <div ng-message="minlength">The value entered is too short</div>
</div>
</form>
```

**EDIT : this is a working sample**

1- Index.html should be :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="registerApp" ng-controller="RegistrationCtrl">

    <form name="myForm">
        <input type="text" ng-model="field" name="myField" required minlength="5" />
        <div ng-messages="myForm.myField.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
            <div ng-message="minlength">The value entered is too short</div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

2- app.js

```
angular
    .module('registerApp', ['ngMessages'])
    .controller('RegistrationCtrl',
  ['$scope',
     function ($scope) {
         var vm = this;
     }]);
```

**Edit 2:** basically for ngMessages because it is a directive you only need to add the module that directive was defined into the app module dependencies,  and don't need to inject anything into the controller. Maybe you can get the error messages to be bound from the controller.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Omar.Alani  It would be very helpful if you could explain to me what you put in the module dependencies and what you put in the controller dependencies.  I get confused on what goes in each.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting exactly same error, because of typo/ wrong syntax.

Note the `ng-message` instead of `ng-messages` in first element:

```
<div ng-message="myForm.myField.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I found the typo.

Comment: Your example has yet another typo. The parent directive should be `ng-messages="myForm.myField.$error"` and not `ng-message` (note the trailing 's'). That's probably why @brabertaser1992 said you should read the docs.

Comment: @Robin: Look at what I wrote: `Note the ng-message istead of ng-messages in first element`

Comment: That is exactly what's wrong here. *Read the docs*: 
> ngMessages manages the state of internal messages within its container element. The internal messages use the ngMessage directive and will be inserted/removed from the page depending on if they're present within the key/value object.

Comment: Yes, I put an example of incorrect use.I spent about 2h finding out what's wrong so decided to give additional answer at SO, but if it's too confusing I think it's better to delete it

Comment: it's your decision, let it be... i see that you have -1, so i gave you +1 )

Comment: ng-messages subordinate ng-message

Comment: @MarcCondon > True, please read whole answer before downvoting.